# Multiple strands of hair

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that connotes *multiple strands of hair*?

Comment: If hair is the conversation piece....what is wrong with "strands"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's usually referred to as a *lock* of hair. Multiple locks are tresses.

Edit: (Actually, *tress* is also a synonym for [lock](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lock).) But one seldom hears *tress* in its singular form, whereas *lock* is familiar in either case.

> a. A length or curl of hair; a tress.

Comment: Yes, I thought about *lock*, but what about hair that is long and straight?

Comment: @Jen: locks don't have to be curly.

Comment: I don't hear lock and think multiple strands of hair; I envision a "bunch" of hair.

Comment: @Aaron: Now you're splitting hairs. :)